# Why won't EF Core update this item on my database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble updating an item on my database. I've tried several different ways, but nothing seems to work. Here is my latest attempt:

```
public async Task<Finding>  InsertOrUpdateItemAsync(Item localItem)
{
    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
       context.Items.Update(localItem);
       context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When SaveChanges executes, I get the following error message: "The instance of entity type ItemStatus cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value ['ItemStatusId: 4'] is already being tracked.

Here are the relevant properties of my Item model:

```
public class Item
{   
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public ItemStatus InitialStatus { get; set; }

    public ItemStatus FinalStatus {get; set; }
}
```

And here are the relevant properties from the ItemStatus class:

```
public class ItemStatus
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ItemStatusId { get; set; }

    public string ItemStatusName{ get; set; }
]
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have checked to make sure I don't have an undisposed context somewhere. Also, when I look at the change tracker, I can see that it is tracking an entry from each row on the ItemStatus table. This doesn't seem right. Shouldn't it only track the ItemStatus that has been assigned to localItem rather than all the related entities?

I am calling the method from here:

savedItem = awaitdataService.InsertOrUpdateFindingAsync(ItemToDisplay);

The various properties of ItemToDisplay are bound to dropdown lists in the UI. I have verified that these properties are being assigned correctly before being sent to the InsertOrUpdateFindingAsync method.

I have also tried a this for the InsertOrUpdate method:

```
public async Task<Finding>  InsertOrUpdateItemAsync(Item localItem)
{
    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
       Item itemFromDb = context.Items.Where(i => i.ItemId == localItem.ItemId).FirstOrDefault();
       itemsFromDb = localItem;
       context.Items.Update(localItem);
       context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: `context.SaveChanges();` is missing.

Comment: Sorry, I do have that in my code, but left it out of my code sample above. I have now added it.

Comment: I haven't had luck with EF core crawling my object trees to update/insert/add/upsert. Update each child object manually `context.ItemStatuses.Update(localItem.InitialStatus)`

Comment: I don't think the issue can be identified with just the code you have provided here. Can you include how, and where you are calling `InsertOrUpdateItemAsync`? Maybe even where you are querying/creating the object you wish you update, as well.

Comment: Please try the following and tell us how it goes:

`context.Entry(Items).CurrentValues.SetValues(localItem);
context.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Youshell - Thanks. I had to modify a bit to get the code to execute: I used this: context.Entry(itemFromDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(localItem). I don't get an error. However, itemFromDb.InitalStatus gets assigned null, rather that the value of localItem.IntitialStatus, so the database is not updated.

Comment: Could you add how the incoming object (localItem) looks in your InsertOrUpdateItemAsync method?

Comment: When I examine the localFinding object after it has come into the InsertOrUpdateAsync method, I can see that the InitalStatus is set to {Status 2}. When examine {Status 2}, I see that it does have a StatusId of 2. So this is as I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

You apparently save a `localItem` that refers to two `ItemStatus` objects both having `ItemStatusId` = 4. The cause of the error is that these `ItemStatus` objects are two instances instead of one. The `Update` command tries to attach both of these instances to the context.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Make sure that if both statuses in `Item` are identical they both refer to the same `ItemStatus` object. Depending on where `localItem` comes from, this may require JSON serializer settings or a modification in the code that constructs the `localItem` object.
2. (Preferred) Add the primitive foreign properties `InitialStatusId` and `FinalStatusId` to `Item` and only set these properties, not the references. Then the update is a simple update of scalar properties.

Comment: When I expand the localFinding object after it has come into the InsertOrUpdateAsync method, I can see that the InitalStatus is set to {Status 2}.When I examine the context, I see that it includes all of the items in the Statuses table. This, of course, includes Status 2 with a StatusId of 2. Co could this be the issue? I mean is EF Core trying to track the InitialCoreStatus of Status 2 and the Status 2 from the list of available statuses as two different objects?

Comment: Is this first snippet the full code? There's seems to be nothing that could trigger loading all `ItemStatus` into the new context.

Comment: It is. I'm wondering if there is something wrong with my Item model. From the samples I have seen online, it seems like I should have an ItemStatusId property in front of both InitialItemStatus and FinalItemStatus. But I know a class can't have two properties with the same name.

Comment: I can't tell. The FK properties don't have to have the same name: `InitialStatusId`, `FinalStatusId`. Whatever it is that causes the duplicate attaching problems, this will solve it.

Answer (score -2):

Because

```
savedItem = awaitdataService.InsertOrUpdateFindingAsync(ItemToDisplay);
```

this variable is itemtodisplay, you have to read from once and you keep this data in this variable, so your context to database, tracked this record when you read.

```
public async Task<Finding>  InsertOrUpdateItemAsync(Item localItem)
{
    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
       context.Items.Update(localItem);
       context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Then here when you sent this variable to there, there is already tracked variable, you tried to track it one more time.

There are 2 solutions:

1. Read this record with `.AsNoTracking` so it will not be tracked
2. When your update method you need to read one more time, like searching with id and keep it in another variable, and assign the parameters which you want to update to sent variable to new read one. then save it so it will not tracked, because there is a new read, actually you read this with tracking parameter because you don't need to add `.AsNoTracking` here, but it will create a problem because you are trying to change something on same tracked context.

I will add basic code based on my 2. desc.

```
    public async Task<Finding>  InsertOrUpdateItemAsync(Item localItem)
    {
        using (var context = new AppDbContext())
        {
           var data = context.Items.Where(x => x.Id == localItem.Id).FirstOrDefault();
           data.Name = localItem.Name;
           context.Items.Update(data);
           context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I hope I described it well.

But note: using update method is not the best, because in that example I only want to update name property but it will create query that updates all columns. You should do it with out update, else there is 2 option here, if write update, it says hey EF mark all need to update, so it creates a query that to update all columsn. But this data is already tracked, if you change name like example EF Core knows it so you should only write there, `SaveChanges();` or second method is if you want to update only one record, but your record is read with `.AsNoTracking`, you should access the context, get entries and change the field as modified

```
public void ContextAttach(TEntity entity)
{
    _dataContext.Attach(entity);
    _dataContext.Entry(entity).Property(Name).IsModified = true;
}
```

https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2020/01/17/dontcallupdate/

Comment: All attempts in the question use a new context. This is not an issue of previously attached entities. Your answer is off the mark.

Comment: no, I do not agree with you this is the solution. This issue comes from when you tried to track two times, and I explained it well !!!  there is two way to do it, other ways create and error it is normal to see this who don't know how ef works.

Comment: no way bro, I was in deep dive into this. This is a tracking error update method means change those records entity status to uptated, but those records are already tracked once, so you cant use update method, you will just do your changes and run savechanges, because those records are already tracked !!.
https://medium.com/@fatih_yildizli/entity-framework-core-best-practices-dd567c998054
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265286/ef-core-best-practice-to-update-complexe-objects

Comment: public async Task<Finding>  InsertOrUpdateItemAsync(Item localItem)
{
    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
       context.Items.Update(localItem);
       context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

This accepts an argument yeah? This method works for updating it means this record is already registered. How you would like to achieve this registered record?

Comment: when you read this entity from somewhere to send this function, if you read without asnotacking, ef will track it once, and you use update method on the same entity(it send the reference because it is class, class is reference type values), it will creates an error for tracked twice